# Комбинаторика(Деревья на участках)

Tags: комбинаторика, дискретная-математика

Сколькими способами можно рассадить деревья трех видов: 5 вишен, 6 яблонь и 10 абрикос на трех разных участках, если на каждом участке должны быть деревья всех видов.

Как я понял у нас по-любому 9 деревьев всегда будут засажены заранее, и нужно считать комбинации с оставшимися 2 вишнями, 3 яблонями и 7 абрикосами. У меня есть версия, т.к нам не важно расположение на участке 12!/(3!*9!), но не знаю правильно ли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Про фиксированные 9 деревьев совершенно верно.

С остальными деревьями так - каждый вид рассаживается независимо, и общее число вариантов есть произведение количеств вариантов рассадки для каждого вида.

Количество вариантов рассадки `N` деревьев по `K=3` участкам можно получить следующим образом - выстроим ряд  из  `N+K-1` **объектов** - `N` деревьев и `K-1` **заборчиков между участками** (в ряду заборчики могут быть как между деревьев, так и слева и справа от них).

`N` этих мест занимают деревья, так что количество вариантов есть количество сочетаний `C(N+K-1, N)`. Эквивалент - существует `C(N+K-1, N)` слов длиной `N+K-1` битов, содержащих ровно `N` единичных битов.

([аналог по методу шаров и перегородок, теорема 2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA))

Получается

```
V(N) = C(N+K-1,N) = C(N+2,N) = (N+1)(N+2)/2
```

Осталось посчитать

```
V(2)*V(3)*V(7) = 6*10*36
```